# (React-Native) Why render twice?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hello I'm working on a gps program. However, there was a problem with the render function. The problem is my function is called twice when called.

**This is my code**

```
playSound = async() => {
    console.log('Loading Sound');
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
       require('../sound/test.mp3')
    );
    
    console.log('Playing Sound');
    await sound.playAsync(); }

componentDidMount(){
    this.interval = setInterval(this.geoLocation, 3000);
    
}
render() {
    if(this.state.lat>10 && this.state.lat<11){
      this.interval2 = setInterval(this.playSound, 2000);
      Alert.alert(
        "",
        "reach goal.",
        [
          { 
            text: "turn off", onPress: () => clearInterval(this.interval2)
          }
        ]
      );
      clearInterval(this.interval)
    }
```

How can I fix it? Help me please..

Comment: I work mainly with functional components, but any time you change the state in a functional component `setIterval()` it serenaders that component. Im assuming its the same for a class component.

Comment: Do I have to use `setInterval()` only once?

Comment: Can you explain exactly how do you want to call `playsound` method? Or simply, when should the sound be played?

Comment: You shouldn't know or care how many times React renders your components unless there's a performance problem. Arbitrary side-effects (like window.alert) in render functions are not supported, and the docs are pretty clear about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the development environment, React deliberately call the render method twice to detect issues.

Since you are calling the `setInterval` function inside render method, please put a condition to check if it is already set before setting the interval.

Something like:

```
if(this.state.lat>35.83025 && this.state.lat<35.8303 && !this.interval2){
```

You can check [this](https://mariosfakiolas.com/blog/my-react-components-render-twice-and-drive-me-crazy/) blog to know more. Also, you can try to build the app and check if there are still double renders, and they shouldn't be.

But ideally, you should not call any effect in the render method.
use life cycle methods, like `componentDidUpdate` here, to check changes in state or props and set the interval in it. Otherwise, you can also set the interval at `componentDidMount` depending on the implementation.